# Sort grouped items in a jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm working on a jquery datatable which has grouped data, on a name column.
I've below code to initialize the datatable. I'm not able to sort grouped items in the datatable. I searched but could only find a couple of similar questions having no answers.

Input data:

```
company name     dateFoundedIn     employee     age
abc               08/21/1998       s1           40
                                   s2           50
                                   s3           45
xyz              02/17/1980        e1           30
                                   e2           38
```

When I click on dateFoundedIn column name it should sort groups according to date.

My code:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "columns": columns,
        "data": dataForTable,
        "sScrollY": "500px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bJQueryUI":true,
        "bSort":true,
        "bPaginate":true,
        "sPaginationType":"simple",
        "iDisplayLength": 30,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "sWidth": "10%", "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [0]}],

    }).rowGrouping({
        bExpandableGrouping: true,
        iGroupingColumnIndex: [1],
        bHideGroupingOrderByColumn: false,
        bExpandSingleGroup: false,
        asExpandedGroups: []
    });
```

Few similar questions:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/issues/29

https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/13134/row-grouping-sort-by-number-of-rows-in-each-group

Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe convert the dates to milliseconds using the new Date() object. Then you can sort like numbers. EDIT : I never used this plugin

Comment: The problem is, when I use rowGrouping({}); all the sorts are always applicable for rows inside each group and not groups themselves. I wish to sort groups when date column is sorted.

Comment: @tanmayub Did you find a solution for this? I am facing a similar issue.